# count_if third argument implementation using my own class

Tags: c++, c++11

I am having trouble coding a function to correctly pass an argument to count_if of  algorithm libary.

here is my code.

```
int range = count_if(empVect.begin(), empVect.end(), empVect.InRange(200,399));
```

inRange function implementation is:

```
bool Employee::inRange(double min, double max)
{
if (nIncome > min && nIncome < max)
return true;
return false;
}
```

compiler error: class "std::vector>" has no member "InRange"

I have a class of Employee with 2 strings and 3 double member variables.
I have hard coded the vector creation in my main and need to display number of employees within a certain range of income. Required to use only count_if or lambda function as per assignment requirments. 
Thanks.

Comment: "compiler error: class "std::vector>" has no member "InRange"" Well this says everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`empVect` is a `std::vector<Employee>`, it has no `InRange` member function that accepts anything. That function is a member of your `Employee` class. You need to define a functor that will call that member on each instance of the vector with the arguments you passed. A simple lambda will do the trick:

```
int range = count_if(empVect.begin(), empVect.end(), [](Employee const& e){
               return e.InRange(200,399);
            });
```

You'll also need to fix `inRange` to be a const member function, because `e` is a reference to a const `Employee`. Aspire to write const correct code. If a member doesn't modify any member data, mark it const by default.